# Javascript help for UNITY Game Engine

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding so I have no idea what I'm doing besides what I've had to do in like... the last three days. 
I just want the player to walk into a collider to trigger a Canvas UI, and then have the Canvas disappear when you exit the collider. Here is my code so far:

```
// JavaScript source code

function OnTriggerEnter(Col : Collider)
{
    if(Col.tag == "Player")
{
    myCanvas.active = true;
}

}

function OnTriggerExit(Col : Collider)
{
    if(Col.tag == "Player")
    {
        myCanvas.active = false;
    }

}
```

Even though I didn't get any errors and it plays, I'll enter the collider area and the Canvas won't show up, and when I exit the collider it's like it exits out of play mode...
Help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you get the GameObject that the Canvas component resides on.  Set this object to inactive.
    canvasObj.SetActive(false);

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

If you want to enable/disable the component (e.g. myCanvas is a reference to a Canvas) you need to use .enabled

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enabling-disabling-components